# serial is print twice?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, c, sketch

I have a problem , when send 1 or 0 by Bluetooth module the serial monitor print two time **(RECEIVED SMS)** . what's the wrong ?

**This is my code  :**

```
   char BluetoothData = 0 ; 
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
    for (int pin = 1; pin <= 13; pin++)
     {
       pinMode(pin, OUTPUT); // sets the digitals pin  as outputs
       digitalWrite(pin, LOW); // sets the digitals pin off defult intial states 
     }  
       Serial.println("ALL LEDs NOW OFF \n "); 
       Serial.println("Please, Enter : ( 1 to Turn on All LEDs )  or ( 0 to Turn off LEDs ) \n");
}
void loop() {            
  // read the sensor:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

        BluetoothData = Serial.read();
            Serial.print("*** RECEIVED SMS *** : ==>> ");
            Serial.println(BluetoothData);

        if (BluetoothData == '1'){ 
        for (int Pin = 1; Pin <= 13; Pin++) {
          digitalWrite(Pin, HIGH);
          }  
          Serial.println("ALL LEDs NOW ON");
         }
        // turn all the LEDs off:
   else if (BluetoothData == '0') {
        for (int Pin = 1; Pin <= 13; Pin++) {
          digitalWrite(Pin, LOW);
          }
          Serial.println("ALL LEDs NOW OFF"); 
         }
  }
   delay(100);  
}
```

**This is photo for serial monitor**

[image]

Comment: Please do not post photos of the output, rather select the text, then copy/paste the text into the question, as indented code

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: the posted code does not contain a `main()` function, not the necessary `#include` statements.  So how are we to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I cannot understand all the functions and terms of the site.  I weak in that, is there a video that explains the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the first time because you received the character '1' or '0'.
The second character is probably a '\0' or '\d', an `end-of-string` or `end-of-line` character.

You can easily check this by printing the value of each received character, like

```
Serial.println((int)(BluetoothData));
```

You probably see the value for '0' (48), '1' (49), end of string '0' of end of line '13' or maybe '10' (new line).

Comment: thanks a lot man , true solution :)

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In the Arduino IDE you should select "No Line Ending" from the menu, instead of "New line". Otherwise you are sending an extra "\n".